# did cobalt support codecs "opus"?

Tags: cobalt

we try to enable codec "opus" in isTypeSupported() to stream opus data.
but Youtube will raise an error message.

after we trace cobalt source code, cobalt didn't deliver data by AudioRenderer::WriteSample().
 and we found cobalt did not compile "opus_audio_decoder.cc". 

so, we are confuse about cobalt can parse opus data now.

Answer (score 0):

Cobalt platform-independent code doesn't currently support Opus out of the box. I think it might not be too hard to get it working. If so, you could submit a patch to the OSS project.